Antiferromagnetic Heisenberg Hamiltonian
I am studying Tauber's Critical dynamics, specifically exercise 3.5 on the critical dynamics of isotropic antiferromagnets - Model G. My question is how one gets a course-grained effective Hamiltonian of the form:
$$ \mathcal{H} = \int d^dx\left( \frac{1}{2}r \psi^2 + \frac{1}{2}|\nabla\psi|^2 + \frac{u}{4!}\psi^4 + \frac{1}{2}M^2 - \vec{h}\cdot \vec{\psi} - \vec{H}\cdot \vec{M}\right)$$
from the microscopic antiferromagnetic Heisenberg Hamiltonian:
$$ H = -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{ij}J_{ij} \vec{S}_i\cdot \vec{S}_j - \sum_i\vec{H}_i\cdot \vec{S}_i $$
Here $\vec{\psi}_i = \eta_i \vec{S}_i$ is the staggered field and $J_{ij}<0$ are nearest neighbor antiferromagnetic couplings. I know how one gets the coarse-grained Hamiltonian from the ferromagnetic Heisenberg model, and I see how one can get the same for the staggered field. Specifically I don't understand how the terms $M^2$ and $\vec{h}\cdot \vec{\psi}$ appear. In Tauber we also derive the Poisson brackets between the staggered field and the magnetization, although I am not sure this would be relevant for the derivation of the Hamiltonian. This is also given in Hohenberg and Halperin "Theory of dynamic critical phenomena", Sec. VII, A, 1. Thank you!
